# Converting DataContext to a Local Value

Tags: wpf, datacontext

How would one propogate changes to properties of the `DataContext` in the designer to the actual datacontext object? Is that possible?

Here is what I tried - I convert the DataContext to a local value in XML - thinking any changes I make to it in the designer would be reflected on the DataContext object.

This is the SSCCE. I have a UserControl called MammalUC and a class called Kangaroo. I use the object of the class Kangaroo as the DataContext. The below code shows that.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WPFTestABC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// User Control :  Interaction logic for MammalUC.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MammalUC : UserControl
    {
        public MammalUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Kang = new Kangaroo();
            this.DataContext = Kang;
        }

        private Kangaroo kang;

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the datacontext.
        /// </summary>
        [Category("ForDebug")]
        [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
        public Kangaroo Kang
        {
            get{ return kang;}
            set {kang = value;}
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Kangaroo class.
    /// </summary>
    public class Kangaroo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int age;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set
            {
                age = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Age");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I bind the Age property to the UserControl like this -

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFTestABC.MammalUC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTestABC"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" Background="#FFD88787"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I then place the MammalUC on to a window. Then convert the Kang object to a local value (I've tried as a Static Resource also). In the designer property grid I change the value, but I don`t see the value being updated.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestABC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTestABC"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <!--<Window.Resources>
        <local:Kangaroo x:Key="Kangaroo1" Age="65"/>
    </Window.Resources>-->
    <Grid>
        <!--Using Static Resource -->
        <local:MammalUC HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="210,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
            <!--Converting to local resource-->
            <local:MammalUC.Kang>
                <local:Kangaroo Age="85"/> <!--Value never updates-->
            </local:MammalUC.Kang>
        </local:MammalUC>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: How would you propagate changes in the properties of a given object, to the object itself? That makes no sense. It *is* itself.

Comment: @Ed - Maybe I should have phrased the question better. Why are the changes not being registered? The UI does not update.

Comment: I see I answered a question of yours a few days ago and you didn't bother to accept it as correct, although you seemed to think it had solved your problem. If an answer resolves the problem you have, you should accept it.

Comment: @Ed - Sorry about that. I missed it. Marked your solution as the answer. Will do a better job.

Comment: @SanMor, what is the advantage of additional property for DataContext object? `<local:MammalUC.DataContext><local:Kangaroo Age="85"/></local:MammalUC.DataContext>`.  DataContext can contains any object and directly accessed by bindings

Comment: @ASh - I was looking for a way to use the PropertyGrid in the designer to make changes that would be reflected at design time. Now I can select the DataContext object in the PropertyGrid and make changes to it. Unless ofcourse there is a more straightforward way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then convert the Kang object to a local value

I don't have a good guess about what you're trying to say there. I don't see any object being converted to anything, and I don't know what you mean by "local value". I don't know what you think you're doing.

But here's what you *are* doing:

```
<!--Using Static Resource -->
<local:MammalUC HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="210,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
    <!--Converting to local resource-->
    <local:MammalUC.Kang>
        <local:Kangaroo Age="85"/> <!--Value never updates-->
    </local:MammalUC.Kang>
</local:MammalUC>
```

There is no "static resource" in this XAML and no "local resource". [You should find out what the word "resource" means in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources).

What you are doing is *replacing* the `Kang` property's existing value with a new instance of the `Kangaroo` class.

Why doesn't that work? Here's why:

```
    private Kangaroo kang;

    /// <summary>
    /// This only becomes the datacontext if you explicitly assign it 
    /// to this.DataContext.
    /// </summary>
    [Category("ForDebug")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public Kangaroo Kang
    {
        get{ return kang;}
        set {kang = value;}
    }
```

You never told anybody you changed it. You aren't updating the data context. Back in the constructor, you set the `DataContext` to the value that `Kang` had *at that moment in time*. What happens when you give `Kang` a new value? Nothing much. It sets private `kang`, and that's it. Of course it doesn't update the `DataContext`; you never told it to.

The `Age` property of `Kangaroo` raises `PropertyChanged` when it changes, so that works. There's nothing comparable happening with `Kang`. Now, controls don't use `INotifyPropertyChanged`; they use dependency properties. Dependency properties also raise notification events when they change, but you can also put bindings on them in XAML, so they're more suitable for controls.

You could add a new dependency property of type `Kangaroo` and have it update the `DataContext`, but there's a simpler way to do that.

Here's what you could do to fix this problem: Get rid of `private Kangaroo kang;` and change the property as follows.

```
    public Kangaroo Kang
    {
        get { return (Kangaroo)DataContext; }
        set { DataContext = value;}
    }

    public MammalUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //  This sets the DataContext. 
        Kang = new Kangaroo();
    }
```

`DataContext` is a dependency property. Set it, and notifications will fly behind the scenes. Things will happen.

You can't make `Kang` the target of a binding. For that, you'll have to go and make it a dependency property:

```
#region Kang Property
public Kangaroo Kang
{
    get { return (Kangaroo)GetValue(KangProperty); }
    set { SetValue(KangProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty KangProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Kang), typeof(Kangaroo), typeof(MammalUC),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
#endregion Kang Property
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="WPFTestABC.MammalUC"
    ...blah blah blah...
    DataContext="{Binding Kang, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    >
```

Then you could give your main viewmodel a `public Kangaroo SelectedKangaroo { /* INPC garble */ }` property, and bind it in your  main window:

```
<local:MammalUC Kang="{Binding SelectedKangaroo}" />
```

Comment: @SanMor Good catch.

Comment: So, the take away from your really nicely explained solution - I wasn`t updating the DataContext, and words "at that moment in time" makes so much sense. I did try both the solutions, they both work, I did make a small edit to the Dependency Property solution. Now any edits to the DataContext object are reflected in the UI and that is what I was after. And I was trying to make Kang a target for binding, and then I saw your edits. Thank you!